# Select on change event disappear after tr modification

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, events, onselect

I have list of rows and one cell with select. One row is hidden. I use it as a form to add new row. On document ready I select all select fields and add on change event for all of them:

```
const supplierFields = $('select[name$="supplier"]');
supplierFields.on('change', async (select) => {
        //custom logic here..
    });
```

When I use hidden row to add new row I select it and add data:

```
const emptyForm = EstimatesTable.visualization.formSet.find( '.empty-form').prev('tr');
```

When new row is added event on select field disappears, but other events on inputs for example stays. Where could be an issue?
When I inspect elements on browser hidden row and other old rows has events. After refresh event appears because of on document ready function.

Comment: Dynamically added DOM elements don't inherit/copy original event listeners.

Comment: Then why events on inputs are copied?

Comment: Maybe you have delegated the inputs. We cannot tell since you did not show enough code and HTML

Comment: Not sure there's anything about "copying elements" here, but this line *"when new row is added"* indicates the rows are being added after the event has been assigned.  Events only apply to elements that exist at the time the code runs - you need to use event delegation to apply events automatically to new elements.